# Create a matrix with np.random.normal

Tags: python, matrix, random, distribution, gaussian

I need to create an nxn matrix in which the numbers in the cells are distributed following a Gaussian distribution.
This code may not go well because it fills a cell with a sequence.
how can I do?

```
mu, sigma = 8, 0.5 # mean and standard deviation

def KHead(nx, ny, mu, sigma):
KH0=np.zeros((nx,ny))
N=1000
for k in range(1,ny-1):
    for i in range(0,nx-1):
        KH0[(i,k)]= np.random.normal(mu, sigma, N )

return KH0
```

Comment: np.random.normal(3, 2.5, size=(2, 4)). more at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html?highlight=random%20normal#numpy.random.normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited for border of zeros**

`np.random.normal` takes a `size` keyword argument.
You can use it like this:

```py
KH0 = np.zeros((nx, ny))
KH0[1:-1,1:-1] = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (nx -2, ny - 2))
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but if I want to create borders with 0 value?

Comment: thank u sooo much! 
Could I contact you to report any problems I have with a program?

Comment: @Steren I won't always be available, but the community here on SO is wonderful and I'm sure someone will always pop up when you need help

Comment: thanks anyway. I have to deliver a project to the university but it is difficult to ask for specific help here. I'll try...  @SimoneCrane